# Recreating a highcharts donut chart in highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am learning highcharter, and trying to create a graph similar to the following donut chart in R http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut/grid-light, and I encountered some issues.
I get data from SQL database, so it is stored as a table, sth like:

```
Browser      Version             Pct        Total
Chrome       Chrome v30.0        0.14       24.4
Chrome       Chrome v31.0        1.24       24.4
Chrome       Chrome v32.0        0.55       24.4
...
```

My code is:

```
highchart() %>%
hc_title(text = "Browsers Data") %>%
hc_add_series_labels_values(unique(table$Browser), unique(table$Total), type = "pie", size = '60%',
                            dataLabels = list(distance = -50, 
                                              color = '#ffffff')) %>%
hc_add_series_labels_values(table$Version, table$Pct, type = "pie",  size = '100%', innerSize = "60%") %>%
hc_add_theme(hc_theme_gridlight())
```

This gives me the graph, but I am not sure how to make labels that are too long not to show up, simply

```
dataLabels = list(formatter = "!# function(){
return this.y > 100 ? this.point.name : null;
                                   }!#")
```

doesn't work.

And, also, my colors are different. I would like to have a browser and all its versions the same colour. any advice how to deal with those?

Comment: I think that you should check something else than this.y in your formatter. maybe number of chars in your dataLabel string? About your different colors: could you be more specific about your problem? Maybe you should set colorByPoint parameter of your series to false?

Comment: Hi, first of all the `!# function() ... !#` is for rCharts package, for highcharter package you need to use `JS(" function() ... ")`. Finally the color is given by the theme which is `hc_theme_gridlight`, if you want change the default colors you can add `  %>% hc_colors(c("red", "blue", "green"))`

Comment: Thank you, I will try the function. By the colours I mean to have Chrome on pie chart and then on the donut one all versions of chrome the same colour, what I was getting right now is chrome for example green, and then each version of it another new colour.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but you can achieve this using the formatter argument to dataLabels, by specifying which labels should be shown based on the size of their slice. You can adjust this upwards or downwards as you which.

I don't have your data so I am using my own, adapted from the demo. Also, highcharter has moved on from `hc_add_series_labels_value()` so I am providing slightly different code to yours.

Chart code:

```r
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(type = "pie", data = browserData, hcaes(name, y), 
                size = "60%", name = "Browers", center = c(50, 50), 
                dataLabels = list(distance = -50, 
                                  formatter = JS("function () {
                                                  return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
  }"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(type = "pie", data = versionsData, hcaes(name, y), size = "80%", name = "Versions", 
                innerSize = "60%", dataLabels = list(formatter = JS("function () {
      // display only if larger than 1
      return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' +
        this.y + '%' : null;
    }"), id = 'versions')) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Browser market share, January, 2018") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = 'Source: <a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank">statcounter.com</a>')
```

Output:

[image]
Data:

```r
dput(versionsData)

structure(list(color = c("rgb(195,255,176)", "rgb(192,255,173)", 
"rgb(189,255,170)", "rgb(186,255,167)", "rgb(183,255,164)", "rgb(180,255,161)", 
"rgb(178,255,159)", "rgb(175,255,156)", "rgb(172,255,153)", "rgb(169,255,150)", 
"rgb(166,255,147)", "rgb(163,255,144)", "rgb(161,254,142)", "rgb(158,251,139)", 
"rgb(155,248,136)", "rgb(152,245,133)", "rgb(149,242,130)", "rgb(146,239,127)", 
"rgb(118,118,123)", "rgb(112,112,117)", "rgb(107,107,112)", "rgb(102,102,107)", 
"rgb(97,97,102)", "rgb(92,92,97)", "rgb(87,87,92)", "rgb(82,82,87)", 
"rgb(77,77,82)", "rgb(72,72,77)", "rgb(175,232,255)", "rgb(162,219,255)", 
"rgb(149,206,255)", "rgb(136,193,248)", "rgb(255,214,143)", "rgb(255,205,134)", 
"rgb(255,197,126)", "rgb(255,188,117)", "rgb(255,180,109)", "rgb(255,171,100)", 
"rgb(255,143,179)", "rgb(255,130,166)", "rgb(255,117,153)", "rgb(253,104,140)", 
"rgb(179,184,255)", "rgb(162,167,255)", "rgb(145,150,250)", "rgb(255,255,135)"
), name = c("Chrome v65.0", "Chrome v64.0", "Chrome v63.0", "Chrome v62.0", 
"Chrome v61.0", "Chrome v60.0", "Chrome v59.0", "Chrome v58.0", 
"Chrome v57.0", "Chrome v56.0", "Chrome v55.0", "Chrome v54.0", 
"Chrome v51.0", "Chrome v49.0", "Chrome v48.0", "Chrome v47.0", 
"Chrome v43.0", "Chrome v29.0", "Firefox v58.0", "Firefox v57.0", 
"Firefox v56.0", "Firefox v55.0", "Firefox v54.0", "Firefox v52.0", 
"Firefox v51.0", "Firefox v50.0", "Firefox v48.0", "Firefox v47.0", 
"Internet Explorer v11.0", "Internet Explorer v10.0", "Internet Explorer v9.0", 
"Internet Explorer v8.0", "Safari v11.0", "Safari v10.1", "Safari v10.0", 
"Safari v9.1", "Safari v9.0", "Safari v5.1", "Edge v16", "Edge v15", 
"Edge v14", "Edge v13", "Opera v50.0", "Opera v49.0", "Opera v12.1", 
"Other"), y = c(0.1, 1.3, 53.02, 1.4, 0.88, 0.56, 0.45, 0.49, 
0.32, 0.29, 0.79, 0.18, 0.13, 2.16, 0.13, 0.11, 0.17, 0.26, 1.02, 
7.36, 0.35, 0.11, 0.1, 0.95, 0.15, 0.1, 0.31, 0.12, 6.2, 0.29, 
0.27, 0.47, 3.39, 0.96, 0.36, 0.54, 0.13, 0.2, 2.6, 0.92, 0.4, 
0.1, 0.96, 0.82, 0.14, 7.62)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))

dput(browserData)
structure(list(color = c("#90ed7d", "#434348", "#7cb5ec", "#f7a35c", 
"#f15c80", "#8085e9", "#e4d354"), name = c("Chrome", "Firefox", 
"Internet Explorer", "Safari", "Edge", "Opera", "Other"), y = c(62.74, 
10.57, 7.23, 5.58, 4.02, 1.92, 7.62)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```